# Do generalized linear models allow non-normal response variables, non-normal errors, or both?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, intuition

There are a lot of Generalized Linear Model questions on here, but I couldn't find one that explicitly addressed this point.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) page starts out by saying:

> [T]he generalized linear model (GLM) is a flexible generalization of
>   ordinary linear regression that allows for response variables that
>   have error distribution models other than a normal distribution.

However, the subsequent parts of the Wikipedia page drop the talk of non-normal errors and instead talk about non-normal responses, e.g.

> The general linear model may be viewed as a special case of the
>   generalized linear model with identity link and responses normally
>   distributed.

I get that sometimes a non-normal response variable means that the errors must also be non-normal, but understand from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not) that residuals can be normally distributed while the outcome variable is not. So why does Wikipedia bother talking about non-normal response variables?

Comment: See [Logistic Regression - Error Term and its Distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124818/17230). Note that Wikipedia is talking about response variables that have non-normal distributions, *conditional on the predictors*. In ordinary linear regression, the outcome variable does have a normal distribution, conditional on the predictors: unconditionally it may be have any distribution at all.