# How to write a logit and probit regression equation?

Tags: categorical-data, logit, probit, statsmodels

I have the following linear equation:

Dummy dependent variable = dummy main independent variable + control variable 1, absolute value of changes (also between 0 and 1) + control variable 2, sigma (also between 0 and 1)

I want to know how to exactly write the logit and probit regression equations in a formal academic context.

Regarding the LHS, should this be written as logit(y)/probit(y), or P(y=1 given the RHS)?

If the main Linear Probability Model equation included a fixed effects term and an error term, should those be omitted for the logit and probit models? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Logit Linear Model:**

$$\text{logit: }E(y) = \frac{e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{dummy main IV}}\text{dummy main IV} + \beta_{\text{CV1}}\text{CV1} + \beta_{\text{abs changes}}\text{abs changes} + \beta_{\text{CV2}}\text{CV2} + \beta_{\sigma}\sigma}}{1+e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{dummy main IV}}\text{dummy main IV} + \beta_{\text{CV1}}\text{CV1} + \beta_{\text{abs changes}}\text{abs changes} + \beta_{\text{CV2}}\text{CV2} + \beta_{\sigma}\sigma}}$$

**Probit Linear Model:**

$$\text{probit: }E(y) = \Phi\left(\beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{dummy main IV}}\text{dummy main IV} + \beta_{\text{CV1}}\text{CV1} + \beta_{\text{abs changes}}\text{abs changes} \\+ \beta_{\text{CV2}}\text{CV2} + \beta_{\sigma}\sigma\right)$$

**BONUS Complementary Log-Log Linear Model:**

$$\text{clog-log: }E(y) = 1 - e^{-e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{dummy main IV}}\text{dummy main IV} + \beta_{\text{CV1}}\text{CV1} + \beta_{\text{abs changes}}\text{abs changes} + \beta_{\text{CV2}}\text{CV2} + \beta_{\sigma}\sigma}}$$

**Notes:**

1. Your dependent variable is named $y$.
2. I am assuming that $\sigma$ is a variable that you are conditioning on.
3. I am assuming you want an intercept term ($\beta_{0}$).
4. $\Phi()$ is the [probit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit) (i.e. the inverse normal CDF).
5. The [clog-log function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Complementary_log-log_.28cloglog.29) is another binomial link function.

Please let me know if this serves for what you mean by "a formal academic context": if not I will try to edit to incorporate your feedback.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! I have some questions please. Regarding the LFH, should this be written as logit(y) or P(y =1 given the RHS)?
If the main Linear Probability Model equation included a fixed effects term and an error term, should those be omitted for the logit and probit models? Thanks!

Comment: @David Hey! I am not sure I follow you: what is LFH? What is RHS? You can *certainly* add something like $\text{logit}(y|\text{dummy main IV}, \text{CV1}, \text{abs changes}, \text{CV2}, \sigma)$. Finally, and with utter sincerity, what do you mean by "should?"

Comment: @David There is also not an error term for these models in quite the same sense as for linear regression. See the first answer to [Logistic Regression - Error Term and its Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124818/logistic-regression-error-term-and-its-distribution).

Comment: Hello @Alexis, Thank you again! I meant by RHS = Right Hand Side (of the equation), and LHS = Left Hand Side. Sorry for my typo!

Comment: What do you mean by "$\sigma$"?  It *must* be a number, because the left hand side *must* refer to a *parameter* of a conditional distribution--neither the logit nor the probit is defined for $y=0$ or $y=1$! As a number, $\sigma$ is confounded with $\beta_0$.

Comment: @whuber whoops... yes. More explicit now. I was assuming "sigma" was the name of one of the OP's variables.

Comment: Presumably $y$ is coded to take on just the values $0$ and $1$.  Since neither the logit, probit, nor complementary log-log functions are defined for either of those values, something must be wrong with your formulation.  I believe you are confusing $y$ with its expectation.

Comment: -1 @Alexis Why do you apply the link functions to $y$ on the left hand side _and_ its inverse to the linear predictor on the right hand side of the same equations?

Comment: @JarleTufto Better now?

Comment: @whuber Edited to incorporate your feedback.

Comment: @Alexis. Ok, +1,