# Relationship between a logistic decision function and Gaussian Noise

Tags: distributions, logistic, normal-distribution, density-function, model

Imagine an experiment, in which an observer has to discriminate between two stimulus categories at different contrast levels $|x|$. As $|x|$ becomes lower, the observer will be more prone to making perceptual mistakes. The stimulus category is coded in the sign of $x$. I'm interested in the relationship between two different ways of modeling the observer's "perceptual noise" based on their choices in a series of stimulus presentations.

The **first way** would be to fit a logistic function

$
p_1(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta\cdot x}}
$

where $p_1(x)$ is the probability to choose the stimulus category with positive signs ($S^+$). Here, $\beta$ would reflect the degree of perceptual noise.

A **second way** would be to assume that the observer has Gaussian Noise $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$ around each observation of $x$ and then compute the probability to choose $S^+$ by means of the cumulative probability density function as follows:

$
p_2(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma^2}} dz
$

In this case, $\sigma$ would be an estimate of the perceptual noise.

I have a hunch that both these approaches are intimately related, but I'm not sure how. Is it an underlying assumption of the logistic function that the noise is normally distributed? Is there a formula that describes the relationship between $\beta$ of $p_1(x)$ and $\sigma$ of $p_2(x)$? Are, in the end, $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ essentially identical and could $p_1$ be derived from $p_2$?

Comment: Probabilities are bounded to $[0, 1]$ while normal distribution is unbounded $(-\infty, \infty)$, so probability + Gaussian noise is not probability any more since it goes outside the bounds... What exactly do you mean by their relation?

Comment: Where did you see probability + Gaussian noise? My assumption is that there is Gaussian noise around each observation $x$, where $x$ is the stimulus variable, not a probability.

Comment: Than what you mean by "relation" between them? You could pick arbitrary $\sigma$ to generate $x$ and then multiply it by another arbitrary $\beta$ and use logistic transformation to generate such data, so both can be completely independent from each other.

Comment: I had a typo in $p_2(x)$, maybe things become more clear now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $p_2$ in here. What exactly this ought to be?

Comment: $p_2$ is the probability of choosing the positive stimulus category, given an observation $x$. The idea is that I fit both models ($p_1$ and $p_2$) to the choice data and obtain values for β and σ. One question would be whether the expected values of β and σ are related in terms of a formula.

Comment: I now realize your misunderstanding. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two alternatives to achieve the same thing: modeling noisy perceptual choices. (your first question sounded like you thought that I add Gaussian noise p2 on top of the choice probabilities of p1, which of course would not make sense)

Comment: If I follow you correctly, you are asking how *logit* and *probit* models might be related.  Although the mathematical relationship is not simple, in practice they behave so similarly that they are considered interchangeable.  Replacing the Gaussian error by a double exponential ("Laplacian") error makes the two approaches equivalent.  Perhaps your questions are all satisfactorily addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models?

Comment: Thanks, this question is an excellent resource. The double exponential error would be $\frac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}$ (using the notation of my question)?

Comment: The double exponential distribution is the location-scale family determined by the distribution with density function $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)/2.$

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403575/how-is-logistic-regression-related-to-logistic-distribution/403885#403885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way to model the value $p_1(x)$ is via the **sigmoid** function; the second way to model it, namely $p_2(x)$, is via the **probit** function.

They are not intimately related per se, i.e., one cannot *naturally* get from the sigmoid to the probit or vice-versa. However, the probit function can be used as an approximation to the sigmoid function. In fact, the two functions are closest, around $x=0$, when $p_1(x)$ is approximated by $p_2$ as $p_2\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}x\right)$.

[image: probit-vs-logistic]

This is useful, for instance, in the context of bayesian logistic regresion, where we are required to solve an integral of the form

$$
    \int_{\mathbb{R}} p_1(x) \mathcal{N}(x\vert\mu_x, \sigma_x) dx
$$

Using the sigmoid function $p_1(x)$ makes the integral intractable, but we can make a variational approximation to the integral considering $p_2\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}x\right)$, which turns the problem into a convolution of Gaussians, hence, it has a closed-form solution.